# Unseen initialized objects in another class in Java

Tags: java

To be short, I create a class Something witch have a function with a JFrame where I have a label and a button on it. On the button I have an addActionListener(new changeLabel()). 
I did class changeLabel in the src package for the listener but when I start the application and I click the button throw an NullPointerException on the changeLabel at

> nameLabel.setText("Name changed");

line. I want to mention that if I create this listener class in Something class, work perfectly. 
I don't know why throw null exception because the label is initialized firstly and after that, the button just want to change the text. 
I tryed to make a getFunction, to call that label, I tryed with object Something, with object changeLabel etc... but doesn't work.
Here is some code

```
package trying;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Something {

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel changeName;
    JButton button;
    public void gui(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //is just an example

        changeName = new JLabel("Stefan");
        //is just an example

        button = new JButton("Change");
        button.addActionListener(new changeLabel());
        frame.getContentPane().add(changeName, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Something().gui();
    }
}
```

The listener class

```
package trying;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class changeLabel extends Something implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        changeName.setText("Andrei");
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is that because the `changeLabel` class extends `Something`, it will contain it's own `changeName` variable which is not initialized == `null`.**

You can:

1. make the `changeLabel` implementation private class of Something (good practice) or
2. pass the `JLabel` to its constructor.

**In both ways `changeLabel` should not extend `Something`.**

Code Sample #1:

```
public class Something {

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel changeName;
    JButton button;
    public void gui(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //is just an example

        changeName = new JLabel("Stefan");
        //is just an example

        frame.getContentPane().add(changeName, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        button = new JButton("Change");
        button.addActionListener(new changeLabel());
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Something().gui();
    }

    class changeLabel implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            changeName.setText("Andrei");
        }
    }
}
```

Code Sample #2:

```
public class Something {
    ...
    public void gui() {
        ...
        button.addActionListener(new changeLabel(changeName));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class changeLabel implements ActionListener {
    private final JLabel label;

    public changeLabel(JLabel label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText("Andrei");
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the same way, to have nested classes, but my teachers told to me to have a package with listener class, a package with calculation part.. I develop an application..and I have everything in one class, the rest of the classes are nested. But they told me that is not a good way and I need to separate everything to be readable and easy to modify something in the code if you want.
What can I do to make this possible without extends?